# Debugging Python and C++ in Visual Studio

Tags: python, debugging, native, breakpoints

I want to be able to step through C++ code that is part of a dll used by a Python script.

I have looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/debugging-mixed-mode-c-cpp-python-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019 and I think I've implemented this correctly.  However when ever I enable **Enable Native code debugging** the breakpoints in Python are no longer functioning and it states that no symbols are found in code.

I went to the Visual Studio Python installation and have selected **Python native development tools**

[image: Visual Studio installation]

And the Python symbols have been installed and are present in the active environment:
[image: python symbols]

On the debug tab I have tried setting the interpreter path to python_d.exe and in Debug>Options on the Symbols tab I've selected the associated symbols:
[image: Debug>Options(Symbols)]
I have tried selecting multiple options in the image above with no success.

I suspect it is something simple that I'm doing wrong, any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: I tried on a different computer and got the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same problem and didn't find a solution.

If you want a workaround, try to attach your native code to the `python.exe` process:

1. Start the debugging of your python script (without native support) and wait on some breakpoint
2. Launch your native project in another VisualStudio instance, set needed breakpoint and then go to Debug -> Attach to process, select started python.exe process (you can find it by PID)
3. Continue python execution.

It worked for me. Note that you need your native code to be compiled with debug symbols as well.

Happy bug-hunting! =)